# How do I make the transcript appear on screen

Tags: reactjs, speech-recognition, transcription

I want my website to get audio input from a user who's talking into their mic, and then output what they said onto the screen. I have implemented speech recognition into my react website, but I am unable to see the transcript when I speak into my mic.

**Here is my code related to speech recognition I have**

This is in my main App.js file inside a class called App, this is part of what's being rendered:

```
<p>Microphone: {Dictaphone.listening ? 'on' : 'off'}</p>
<button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Start</button>
<button onClick={SpeechRecognition.stopListening}>Stop</button>
<button onClick={Dictaphone.resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
<p>{Dictaphone.transcript}</p>
```

This is in a separate file called Dictaphone.jsx, I had to make a separate file because I couldn't use hooks inside the App class:

```
import { useSpeechRecognition } from 'react-speech-recognition';

const Dictaphone = () => {
    const {
      transcript,
      listening,
      resetTranscript,
      browserSupportsSpeechRecognition
    } = useSpeechRecognition();

    return null;
};

export default Dictaphone
```

Does anyone know why the transcript of what is being said into the mic doesn't appear on the screen?
Also, when I click the "start" button on the website, my mic turns on (a mic icon pops up on my PC), but the "off" doesn't change to "on", from this piece of code: `<p>Microphone: {Dictaphone.listening ? 'on' : 'off'}</p>`. Does anyone know why it doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two problem:

1.) Dictaphone is not actually a React component (simplifying, a function become a React component if you call them inside the render of App or a child of App) Es:

```
const App = () => {
     return <>
           <Dictaphone />
     </> 
} // <- NOW, React understand that Dictaphone is a component
```

2.) Even if it is a component, you cant access a private attribute from another.

**Then, you can try this code:**

```
const YourParent = () => {

    const dictaphone = {...useSpeechRecognition()};

    return <>
         <p>Microphone: {dictaphone.listening ? 'on' : 'off'}</p>
         <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Start</button>
         <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.stopListening}>Stop</button>
         <button onClick={Dictaphone.resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
         <p>{dictaphone.transcript}</p>
    </>
}
```

**EDIT:**
Ok, if you need to use two different file, i think the only way is to use a [context](https://it.reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

In the dictaphone files:

```
import { useSpeechRecognition } from 'react-speech-recognition';

const DictaphoneContext = React.createContext();

export const Dictaphone = ({children}) => {
    const dictaphone = {...useSpeechRecognition()};
    
    return <DictaphoneContext.Provider value={dictaphone}>
      {children}
    </DictaphoneContext.Provider>
};

export const DictaphoneListening = ({}) => {
    const dictaphone = React.useContext(DictaphoneContext);  
    return <><dictaphone.listening ? 'on' : 'off'}</>
};

export const DictaphoneTranscript = ({}) => {
    const dictaphone = React.useContext(DictaphoneContext);  
    return <>{dictaphone.transcript}</>
};
```

In the main file:

```
return <>
     <Dictaphone>
         <p>Microphone: <DictaphoneListening /></p>
         <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Start</button>
         <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.stopListening}>Stop</button>
         <button onClick={Dictaphone.resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
         <p><DictaphoneTranscript /></p>
     </Dictaphone>
</>
```

Comment: I have two files that I'm talking about in this post. My first file is the App.js file, which has a component class called App inside that's rendering the front end of my website which includes what I mentioned in the first block of code on my post above. The second file is the Dictaphone.jsx file which handles the speech recognition part, and I'm importing this file into the App.js file because speech recognition requires us to use hooks such as this: "const dictaphone = {...useSpeechRecognition()};". In the code you mentioned, which file should I put it in and is it possible for it to work

Comment: Part 2: is it possible for the second file to return HTML and the first file to render its own HTML stuff? Because in the first file, I have to use render() and inside that render, I'm returning the websites HTML. How do I also return the HTML that you put in the "return <> ... </>" part of the code you provided me with? Thank you so much for your help by the way

Comment: I edited the answers... try with context :-)

Comment: In the App.js, this is what I imported: "import Dictaphone, { DictaphoneListening, DictaphoneTranscript } from './Dictaphone.jsx';" (I don't know why but it asked me to put the {}). So now that I put the code you mentioned into the files, respectfully, I get this error: Attempted import error: 'DictaphoneListening' is not exported from './Dictaphone.jsx'. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: fixed, add export before each const, and replace the import with:
import {Dictaphone, DictaphoneListening, DictaphoneTranscript } from ..